# Understanding conflicting Interfaces

Tags: go, struct, interface

I am trying to understand the interface concept.
The following is my test code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

//interface
type InterfaceA interface {
    A() string
}

//interface
type InterfaceB interface {
    A() string
}

//user defined type structure
type structure struct {
    a string
}

//implementing A(), but which A() ?
func (strt structure) A() string {
    return strt.a
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    variable := structure{"hello"}
    fmt.Println(variable.A())
}
```

As per the documentation, I understand that there is no explicit mention of "Implements" like in other languages. But when I call `variable.A()` which interface is my type `structure` using? `InterfaceA` or `InterfaceB` ? Plus, am I actually implementing the interface properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `variable.A()`, you are not using any interfaces. You are calling a method of the type `structure`.

You can call the same method using an interface:

```
variable := structure{"hello"}
var ia InterfaceA
ia=variable
ia.A() // This calls variable.A
var ib InterfaceB
ib=variable
ib.A() // This also calls variable.A
```

Comment: I understand that only when you create an instance of the Interface and assign it to the relevant type, does the interface gets called. So `func (strt structure) A() string` is not implementing an interface, its just a method `A()` of type `structure` and the actual implementation when we assign the interface instance to an instance of type T (in my case `structure`) ? Then why do we need such a concept of interfaces when we can directly call the `variable.A()`?
@Hymns For Disco

Comment: @MikeRoss: you mention you are just learning Go, and continuing on a little further will likely make the answer clear. Take a look at any use of [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) for example, probably the most commonly used interface, with countless implementations.

Comment: Yes, It was a very bad question once I read my question again on why would there be an option. I'll try to learn along the process. I'm sorry. and, thank you @JimB

Answer (score 1):

Your interfaces do not conflict with each other; interfaces do not conflict. They can be redundant with each other as they describe the same thing, but that doesn't create a conflict nor any other tangible problem.

As for which interface is `structure` using: neither. Concrete types such as structs don't use interfaces, they implement them. Implementing of an interface is implicit and automatic. It's just a statement of fact, not a mechanism (until you explicitly use it as such). Further, neither interface is used to any extent in your program. Your `variable` is a `structure` and is being used as a `structure`. It *could* be used as *either* `InterfaceA` or `InterfaceB`, or both of them at different times, but you are doing no such thing in this example.

See Burak's answer for how you *could* use the `structure` value through the interfaces.